# How do I add a button in Sharepoint that when clicked display text below it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, html, design, button

I'm in the process of updating our main page and we have a FAQ section. Right now we have a hyperlink that is the question and when clicked, it takes the user to a sharepoint pdf that has the answer. I'm looking for suggestions on how the below screenshot can be accomplished or if SharePoint even has this functionality?

[image: Before button is clicked]

[image: After button is clicked]

Below is our current sharepoint setup:

[image: Sharepoint]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to create a [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) webpart for your requirements.

Check below official documentation of adding JQuery accordion in SPFx webpart:

[Add jQueryUI Accordion to your SharePoint client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part).

**Note**:

This webpart is using static data to show in accordion. So:

1. You can create a SharePoint list and add all your FAQs in that.
2. Then use SharePoint REST APIs (SPHTTPModule or PnPJS) to fetch the list items and then show it in accordion.

[Retrieve SharePoint List Items Using SharePoint Framework Development Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework-development-model/).

**Update**:

If you are using classic Sharepoint maybe 2019/2016/2013 then you can check below some samples to achieve something similar:

1. [Implementation Of Jquery Accordion For SharePoint List Data](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/implementation-of-jquery-accordion-for-sharepoint-list-data) - Using JSOM.
2. [Displaying items using JQuery Accordion Widget](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245046/displaying-items-using-jquery-accordion-widget) - Using REST APIs.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! I think that would be outside the scope of our current software (we currently don't have Visual Studios license). Our next option I think would just be to have the FAQs answers hidden below the link and have it display once a user clicks on the hyperlink.  Very helpful and I might try your suggestion on my personal PC.

Comment: You don't need Visual studio licences to build SPFx webpart. You will need NodeJS to create a solution using yeomen generator and then you can use any code editor(Visual Studio Code open/free software recommend but not compulsory) of your choice to write/edit code. That's the beauty of SPFx. It is a client side solution.

Comment: Also, if you are using classic sharepoint sites and has access to content editor/script editor then you can get the list items using SharePoint REST API/JSOM and bind it to JQuery accordion.

Comment: Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: I've added some pictures to hopefully clear up which version of sharepoint we're using:

Comment: Yes, I will accept this answer. Thank you Ganesh

Comment: Welcome. Check updated answer for classic experience if you are using 2019/2016/2013.

Comment: You're a life saver Ganesh. Thank you again! :)